# null ExecutionStrategy using AttachedCommandBehavior library

Tags: c#, wpf, attachedbehaviors

I am using Marlon Grech's AttachedCommandBehavior Library  (https://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/04/attachedcommandbehavior-aka-acb/) to bind commands to my WPF window events. I have it successfully working on another user control handling text changed events for a couple of text boxes and it works great. I am now trying to get it to work with a selection changed event on a combo box. I am getting a null reference exception on the ExecutionStrategy in CommandBehaviorBinding.Execute(). I have read through several postings on the null reference exception binding errors using acb. I am not getting a binding error in my output and I have verified that the command is set up in the view model. Here is a portion of my view (I have removed all of the other controls for conciseness):

```
<ScrollViewer DockPanel.Dock="Top" >
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
    <Expander Header="Contact Information">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
            <ItemsControl Style="{StaticResource ControlGrid}" Visibility="{Binding AddressType.Viewable, Converter={StaticResource Bool2Visible}}" IsTabStop="False">
                <Label Grid.Column = "0" Content="{Binding AddressType.Title}" />
                <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="AddressType" VerticalAlignment="Center" SelectedValuePath="Tag" SelectedValue="{Binding AddressType.Value}" 
                          acb:CommandBehavior.Event="SelectionChanged"  
                          acb:CommandBehavior.Command="{Binding OnAddressTypeChangeCommand}"
                          acb:CommandBehavior.CommandParameter="SelectionChanged" >
                    <ComboBoxItem Tag="P" Content="Primary Address" />
                    <ComboBoxItem Tag="S" Content="Send To Address" />
                    <ComboBoxItem Tag="R" Content="Remittance Address" />
                    <ComboBoxItem Tag="M" Content="Marketing Address" />
                    <ComboBoxItem Tag="A" Content="Agent Address" />
                </ComboBox>
            </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </Expander>
</StackPanel>
```

Here is my ViewModel where I set up the commands:

```
   private void InitGroupData(LBBus500.ctGroup group)
{

    // set the default Address Type
    _addressType = ((char)LBBus500.ctListBillConstants.ADDRESS_USAGE_TYPES.ADDRTYPE_PRIMARY).ToString();

    // Load reference tables
    _countryList = GetCountryList();
    _stateList = GetStateList();

    // wire up view event commands
    OnAddressTypeChangeCommand = new SimpleCommand { ExecuteDelegate = x => AddressTypeChangeCommand() };
}

 //OnAddressTypeChange Command
public ICommand OnAddressTypeChangeCommand { get; private set; }
public void AddressTypeChangeCommand()
{
    using (new LBControls.WaitCursor())
    {
        // Process the stuff.
        // code here...
    }
}
```

When I set up a breakpoint on the data bindings for the combo box (i.e., SelectedValue="{Binding AddressType.Value}") I can see the OnAddressTypeChangeCommand is setup and not null. the data context is pointing to my view model (I verified this using Snoop to look at the visual tree). The data coming across in the bindings are working, so I feel I have that set up properly.

I am open to suggestions as to where to look next. I like acb for its simplicity in code, but I'm not married to it yet. I'm only using it in two places so far so if I have to replace it there won't be too much heartburn, although I haven't seen anything that seems as simple to implement.

Thanks in advance.

Eric.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to change things up a bit. I was using Prism, which was a bit overkill for what I needed. I changed to MVVM light and used the EventToCommand model that is in the framework. My combo box now looks like this:

I changed my commands to be RelayCommands and it now works.